# Where can I get SharePoint 2013 training course?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to learn everything about SharePoint 2013. I am looking for videos and course material. I have found many websites providing course material for SharePoint 2013 but I don't know which one to go with. I want to proceed step by step through each topic so that I don't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Refer msdn articles for Sharepoint 2013 detail understanding with examples - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162979.aspx

Refer Inside Sharepoint 2013 book.